# PDE - Method of characteristics and shock waves

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to find a solution to the I.V.P:

$$
u_y + uu_x = -au, a > 0 \\
u(x,0) = f(x), x \in \Bbb{R}
$$

After that i need to find conditions in which $f(x)$ is singular, for :

$$
f(x) = 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 1  & x<0\\ 
 1-x  & 0<x<1\\
0 & x>1
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

——-

I used the mehod of characteristics to solve this PDE, getting:
$$
u = e^{-at}f(s) \\
y = t \\
x = -\frac{e^{-at}}{a}f(s) + s + \frac{f(s)}{a}
$$

Now, i try to isolate $s$ from $x$ equation in order to substitute it in $f(s)$, yet i dont succeed, it stays dependent on $f(s)$..

$$
s = x + \frac{e^{-at}}{a}f(s) - \frac{f(s)}{a}
$$

If i can’t substitute $s$, how can i proceed? Maybe i did something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by “conditions in which () is singular”?

Answer (score 2):

This looks correct. Using $u = e^{-at}f(s)$ we can write the solution in implicit form
$$
u = e^{-at}\, f\!\left(x - \frac{e^{at}-1}{at} ut\right) .
$$
Thus,

- where $f(s) = 0$ we know $u=0$ for $s=x>1$;
- where $f(s) = 1$ we know $u=e^{-at}$ for $s=x-\frac{1-e^{-at}}{a} < 0$;
- between the curves $x=1$ and $x = \frac{1-e^{-at}}{a}$, we have
  $$
  u = e^{-at}\left[ 1 - \left(x - \frac{e^{at}-1}{at} ut\right) \right]
  $$
  which gives us an explicit expression
  $$
  u = e^{-at}\frac{1-x}{1-\frac{1-e^{-at}}{a}}, \qquad \tfrac{1-e^{-at}}{a} < x < 1
  $$
  upon solving with respect to $u$.

Now ask yourself where this piecewise solution is well-defined (sub-domain bounds, vanishing denominator, etc.). You will find useful complements for other $f$ in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2899695/418542).